# BASH + dig on list of domains gives wrong input to dig with domains suffixed with '\013'

Tags: bash, shell-script, dig

I have a list of domains, and I want to use `dig` to check whether those domains have HTTPS records or not. I ran a for loop to do so, and I realized that the reason why I don't have any result is because the domain name read from the file is suffixed with '\013' string when passed to `dig`. Hence, I get NXDOMAIN (even for A records which are available for all the domains in my list).

My domain list is as follows:

```
google.com
cloudflare.com
```

I issue the following loop:

```
for i in $(cat mydomains.csv); do echo $i; dig  $i; sleep 2; done
```

In the output, you can see that `echo $i` shows `google.com` for the first domain, but in the dig command's output, the requested domain is `google.com\013`

```
google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.18.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.1-Ubuntu <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 30386
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com\013.            IN  A

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Fri Feb 02 15:11:29 +08 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 40
```

I bet this is just some stupid encoding problem, but could not figure out how to overcome this. Anyone had the same issue before?

Comment: `13` is Carriage Return aka `CR` aka `^M`. It comes from editing files on Windows. See duplicate on how to remove it.

Comment: Was `mydomains.csv` created on a Windows computer?  I'll bet it has a \013 (carriage return) character at the end of each line, and in your Linux that ends up appending the carriage return to the hostname at the end of each line in the file.  Examining the file with `od -a mydomains.csv` ought to show you the whitespace characters along with the printing ones.

Comment: I don't know if the original file was edited on windows or not, but even if I create a file from scratch, the same thing happens. The duplicate does not really solve my problem. 
```
od -a mydoamins.csv
0000000   1   ,   g   o   o   g   l   e   .   c   o   m  cr  nl
0000016
```

I was editing with nano

Comment: My bad, even though it was edited from scratch on Linux using nano, it still had that problem. Irrespectively, the dos2unix command make it appropriate for me. Thanks